# cohomology isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a  finite dimensional CW complex and $A$ be a closed subset in $X$ and $N$ a regular neighborhood of $A$ that deformation retracts onto it. why do we have for each $i$,

$$H^{i}(X-A;\mathbb Z)\cong H^{i}(X-N;\mathbb Z)$$

My guess: if two subspaces $A$ and $B$  of $X$ are homotopy equivalent then their complements $X-A$ and $X-B$ must be homotopy equivalent and then have the same cohomology groups?

Comment: Do you have some kind of theorem like excision for cohomology? Maybe you can use that.

Comment: Excision is about relative cohomology which is not the case here.

Comment: If am sure you can relate the relative cohomology of say $H^n(X,\emptyset;\Bbb{Z})$ to the cohomology of just $X$...

Comment: You **do** have a pair, though: $(X-A,X-N)$. Use the long exact sequence for that!

Comment: Your guess, by the way, is wrong: two spaces can be in fact homeomorphic without their complements in a bigger space being homotopy equivalent (nor even having the same homology). Google for «Alexander's horned sphere». (If you write what you really meant to write, then... :-) )

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : Writing the long exact sequence of the pair, I see that if for each $i$, $H^i(X-A,X-N)=0$ then $H^i(X-A)\cong H^i(X-N)$ but why could $H^i(X-A,X-N)=0$ be true for each $i$?

Comment: You have to use the fact that you have a deformation retract at some point... Think about this for a while. In a couple of days I'll add an answer.

Comment: Is the following true: if $N$ deformation retracts onto $A$ then $X-A$ deformation retracts onto $X-N$?